# Write a query to list shops, days and time periods in which there are less than two employees working in a shop during its opening hours

Tags: sql, database

I ran into an hard looking problem recently, referring to the figure below I have to write a SQL query to show: the shop, the day of the week, the initial moment and the final moment in which there are less than two employees working in the shop during its opening hours.

[image: ERD]

As far as i know this class of problems are commonly studied in operations research and linear programming, instead of reinventing the wheel I wanted to know if there is a known solution

Aa a reference the query below shows: the shop, the day of the week, the initial moment and the final moment in which there are no employees working in the shop during its opening hours.

```sql
SELECT shop, T.day, MAX(_start) AS _start, _end
FROM (SELECT T1.shop, T1.day, e1 AS _start, MIN(s2) AS _end
      FROM (SELECT shop, SHIFTS.day, employee, SHIFTS.start + SHIFTS.duration AS e1
            FROM SHIFTS
            UNION SELECT SHOPS.name, DAY_OF_WEEKS.name, NULL, opening
                  FROM SHOPS, DAY_OF_WEEKS) AS T1
            JOIN (SELECT shop, SHIFTS.day, employee, SHIFTS.start AS s2
                  FROM SHIFTS
                  UNION SELECT SHOPS.name, DAY_OF_WEEKS.name, NULL, closing
                        FROM SHOPS, DAY_OF_WEEKS) AS T2
                  ON (T1.shop = T2.shop AND T1.day = T2.day AND e1 <= s2)
      GROUP BY shop, T1.day, e1
      HAVING _start != _end) AS T JOIN DAY_OF_WEEKS ON T.day = name
GROUP BY shop, T.day, _end
ORDER BY shop ASC, number ASC, _start ASC;
```

Comment: Without digging deeper, those unions look odd to me.

Comment: @shawnt00 without digging deeper, those unions look definitely even to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention the database, so I'll assume PostgreSQL. Adjust it for anything else.

```
CREATE TABLE days_of_weeks (name VARCHAR, number INTEGER);
INSERT INTO days_of_weeks VALUES ('Monday', 1);

CREATE TABLE shops (name VARCHAR, opening TIME, closing TIME);
INSERT INTO shops VALUES ('Shop One', time '9:00', time '18:00');

CREATE TABLE employees (id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (4);

CREATE TABLE shifts (employee INTEGER, day VARCHAR, start TIME, duration INTERVAL, shop VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO shifts VALUES (1, 'Monday', time '9:00', interval '4 hours', 'Shop One');
INSERT INTO shifts VALUES (2, 'Monday', time '12:00', interval '2 hours', 'Shop One');
INSERT INTO shifts VALUES (3, 'Monday', time '11:00', interval '4 hours', 'Shop One');
INSERT INTO shifts VALUES (4, 'Monday', time '15:00', interval '1 hours', 'Shop One');
```

The critical part of the query is to create table of *events* - when a shop opens or closes and when an employee is coming or leaving, with `emp_change` column showing how this changes the number of employees currently in the shop.

```
WITH shop_days AS (SELECT s.name as shop, d.name as day, s.opening, s.closing
                     FROM shops s CROSS JOIN days_of_weeks d)
SELECT shop, day, opening as t, 0 as emp_change FROM shop_days
UNION ALL
SELECT shop, day, start as t, 1 as emp_change FROM shifts
UNION ALL
SELECT shop, day, start + duration as t, -1 as emp_change FROM shifts
UNION ALL
SELECT shop, day, closing as t, 0 as emp_change FROM shop_days
ORDER BY t;

shop     | day    | t        | emp_change
---------+--------+----------+-----------
Shop One | Monday | 09:00:00 | 0
Shop One | Monday | 09:00:00 | 1
Shop One | Monday | 11:00:00 | 1
Shop One | Monday | 12:00:00 | 1
Shop One | Monday | 13:00:00 | -1
Shop One | Monday | 14:00:00 | -1
Shop One | Monday | 15:00:00 | 1
Shop One | Monday | 15:00:00 | -1
Shop One | Monday | 16:00:00 | -1
Shop One | Monday | 18:00:00 | 0
```

On this we can build a solution. We make heave use of [window functions](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/).

Here's entire query. I added some comments. Try to run each subquery separately starting from the innermost to understand what is going on.

```
/* At last, using group id to roll up the records and also filtering by number of employees
   at this step yielding us final result */
SELECT shop, day, min(t_from) as t_from, max(t_to) as t_to, emp_cnt
  FROM (/* Then we apply moving sum again over to get a group id that we can group by */ 
        SELECT shop, day, t_from, t_to, emp_cnt,
               sum(grp_change) over (partition by shop, day order by t_from, t_to) as grp
          FROM (/* For clarity we should get rid of null ranges like 9:00-9:00 and roll up
                   continuous ranges with the same number of employees, eg. all of
                   14:00-15:00, 15:00-15:00, 15:00-16:00 should be displayed as 14:00-16:00.
                   Lead function helps us spot when the number of employees actually changes */
                SELECT shop, day, t_from, t_to, emp_cnt,
                       case when emp_cnt != lag(emp_cnt) over (partition by shop, day order by t_from, t_to)
                            then 1
                            else 0 end as grp_change
                  FROM (/* With moving total of emp_changes we get the number of all employees
                           in the shop in given time range */
                        SELECT shop, day,
                               t as t_from,
                               lead(t) over (partition by shop, day order by t) as t_to,
                               sum(emp_change) over (partition by shop, day order by t) as emp_cnt
                          FROM (/* We pick events such as opening or closing shop
                                   or employee coming or leaving */
                                WITH shop_days AS (SELECT s.name as shop, d.name as day, s.opening, s.closing
                                                     FROM shops s CROSS JOIN days_of_weeks d)
                                SELECT shop, day, opening as t, 0 as emp_change FROM shop_days
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT shop, day, start as t, 1 as emp_change FROM shifts
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT shop, day, start + duration as t, -1 as emp_change FROM shifts
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT shop, day, closing as t, 0 as emp_change FROM shop_days
                                ORDER BY t
                               ) events
                         ORDER BY t
                       ) event_ranges
                 ORDER BY t_from, t_to
          ) grp_changes
    ORDER BY t_from, t_to) grp
 GROUP BY shop, day, emp_cnt, grp
HAVING emp_cnt < 2
 ORDER BY min(t_from), max(t_to);

shop     | day    | t_from   | t_to     | emp_cnt
---------+--------+----------+----------+--------
Shop One | Monday | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 | 1
Shop One | Monday | 14:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 1
Shop One | Monday | 16:00:00 | 18:00:00 | 0
```

You can make this a bit shorter by removing my comments, also as it's quite nested it might be rewritten using CTEs, but that's just personal taste.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e7f8f/37/0).

Comment: Thank you, it's a very insightful solution and you helped me learn more about the window functions

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up reinventing the well, quite an hexagonal well actually...

```sql
WITH
    CTE1 AS (SELECT shop, T0.day, T0.start, T0.end, employee
             FROM (SELECT shop, SHIFTS.day, employee, SHIFTS.start,
                          SHIFTS.start + SHIFTS.duration AS end
                   FROM SHIFTS
                   UNION ALL SELECT id, name, NULL, opening, opening 
                             FROM SHOPS, DAY_OF_WEEKS
                   UNION ALL SELECT id, name, NULL, closing, closing 
                             FROM SHOPS, DAY_OF_WEEKS) AS T0),
    CTE2 AS (SELECT T1.shop, T1.day, T1.start AS _start, MIN(T2.start) AS _end
             FROM (SELECT shop, CTE1.day, CTE1.start 
                   FROM CTE1
                   UNION ALL (SELECT shop, CTE1.day, CTE1.end FROM CTE1)) AS T1
                 JOIN (SELECT shop, CTE1.day, CTE1.start
                       FROM CTE1
                       UNION ALL (SELECT shop, CTE1.day, CTE1.end FROM CTE1)) AS T2
                         ON T1.shop = T2.shop AND T1.day = T2.day
                WHERE T1.start < T2.start
                GROUP BY T1.shop, T1.day, T1.start),
    CTE3 AS (SELECT shop, T5.day, _start, _end
                FROM (SELECT T3.shop, T3.day, _start, _end, employee
                      FROM CTE2 AS T3 JOIN CTE1 AS T4 ON T3.shop = T4.shop AND T3.day = T4.day
                      WHERE T4.start <= _start AND _end <= T4.end
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT shop, CTE2.day, _start, _end, NULL AS employee FROM CTE2) AS T5
                GROUP BY shop, T5.day, _start, _end
                HAVING COUNT(employee) < 2
                ORDER BY shop, T5.day, _start)
SELECT T6.shop, T6.day, _start, MIN(_end) AS _end
FROM (SELECT shop, T6.day, _start
      FROM CTE3 AS A
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT shop, CTE3.day, _end
                        FROM CTE3
                        WHERE shop = A.shop AND CTE3.day = A.day AND _end = A._start)) AS T6
    JOIN (SELECT shop, CTE3.day, _end
          FROM CTE3 AS B
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT shop, CTE3.day, _start
                            FROM CTE3
                            WHERE shop = B.shop AND CTE3.day = B.day AND _start = B._end)) AS T7
        ON T6.shop = T7.shop AND T6.day = T7.day
    JOIN DAY_OF_WEEKS ON T6.day = name
WHERE _start < _end
GROUP BY T6.shop, T6.day, _start
ORDER BY T6.shop ASC, number ASC, _start ASC;
```

Until someone won't give me a better answer or until I'll end the refactory of the query in a more sensible one, I'll consider the question still open